# How to get width dynamically in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im trying with measure but doesn´t work.

```
 this.refs.tabla.measure(this._getWidth);

_getWidth(a,f,width,h,x,z){
  width = width + '';
  this.setState({width});
  console.log(width);
```

}

this is the error:
index.js:20222 Uncaught TypeError: this.refs.tabla.measure is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `ref` to the element, you can do `this.refs.myelem.clientWidth` (which is zero for elements with no CSS or inline layout boxes) or maybe better `this.refs.myelem.getBoundingClientRect().width`
Not sure where that `measure` method should be coming from.

It can be helpful to remember that React provides a standardised DOM implementation, which means you can normally work with React events and DOM element as if you were dealing with "standard" Js DOM node and events. Both getBoundingClientRect and clientWidth are available on standard DOM nodes too, nothing magic related to React.

Comment: For the record there is nothing `react` about this nor should there be. The best location to make this call would be in the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` that way you can ensure that the `component` is done rendering and catches the update case for new props that may change width.

Comment: true, note also that works under the assumption the width won't change on window resize for example.

Comment: Agreed for appropriate documentation on this refer to the React docs. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html